# command for Discord bot not working

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a "help" command for my Discord bot, but it seems like I can't figure out why. THe purge command also doesn't work, but the rest of them are working. The kick, ping, ban and say commands are all working at the moment. And I'm also trying to figure out how to let the bot log command usage to the console. Any help would be appreciated !

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  // This event will run on every single message received, from any channel or DM.

  // It's good practice to ignore other bots. This also makes your bot ignore itself
  // and not get into a spam loop (we call that "botception").
  if(message.author.bot) return;

  // Also good practice to ignore any message that does not start with our prefix, 
  // which is set in the configuration file.
  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;

  // Here we separate our "command" name, and our "arguments" for the command. 
  // e.g. if we have the message "+say Is this the real life?" , we'll get the following:
  // command = say
  // args = ["Is", "this", "the", "real", "life?"]
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  // Let's go with a few common example commands! Feel free to delete or change those.

  if(command === "ping") {
    // Calculates ping between sending a message and editing it, giving a nice round-trip latency.
    // The second ping is an average latency between the bot and the websocket server (one-way, not round-trip)
    const m = await message.channel.send("Ping?");
    m.edit(`Pong! Latency is ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
  }

  if(command === "say") {
    // makes the bot say something and delete the message. As an example, it's open to anyone to use. 
    // To get the "message" itself we join the `args` back into a string with spaces: 
    const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
    // Then we delete the command message (sneaky, right?). The catch just ignores the error with a cute smiley thing.
    message.delete().catch(O_o=>{}); 
    // And we get the bot to say the thing: 
    message.channel.send(sayMessage);
  }

if (command === "kick") {
    let modRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "[Owner]");
    if(message.member.roles.has(modRole.id)) { 
      let kickMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
      message.guild.member(kickMember).kick();
      message.channel.sendMessage("Member Kicked.");
    } else {
      return message.reply("You dont have the perms to kick members. scrub.");
    }
  }

  if(command === "ban") {
    let modRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "[Owner]");
    if(message.member.roles.has(modRole.id)) { 
      let banMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
      message.guild.member(banMember).ban();
      message.channel.sendMessage("Member banned.");
    } else {
      return message.reply("You dont have the perms to ban members. scrub.");
    }

  if(command === "purge") {
    // This command removes all messages from all users in the channel, up to 100.

    // get the delete count, as an actual number.
    const deleteCount = parseInt(args[0], 10);

    // Ooooh nice, combined conditions. <3
    if(!deleteCount || deleteCount < 2 || deleteCount > 100)
      return message.reply("Please provide a number between 2 and 100 for the number of messages to delete");

    // So we get our messages, and delete them. Simple enough, right?
    const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({count: deleteCount});
    message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
      .catch(error => message.reply(`Couldn't delete messages because of: ${error}`));
  }

  if(command === "help") {
    message.channel.send({embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      author: {
        name: client.user.username,
        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
      },
      title: "Help",
      description: "This message contains all the info of the bot's commands",
      fields: [{
          name: "d!help",
          value: "This command can be used by everyone; displays this message"
        },
        {
          name: "d!ping",
          value: "This command can be used by everyone; it's tells the latency of the bot and the Discord API"
        },
        {
          name: "d!kick <user>",
          value: "This command can be used by [Owner]; it kicks a user"
        },
        {
          name: "d!ban <user>",
          value: "This command can be used by [Owner]; it bans a user"
        },
        {
          name: "d!purge",
          value: "This command isn't working correctly for as far as we know"
        }          
      ],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      footer: {
        text: "© DeltBot Team"
      }
    }
```

Comment: You've seen to have copy and pasted an execive amount of code. Could you edit your post to only include the problem code please

Comment: You should use ```else if``` like ```else if(command === "help")```.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetched variable and bulkDelete needs to be in a `async function` since you're using `await`.